# preserve /t and /n in XML attribute with Java parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

In a XML file parsed to a Document I want to get a XML attribute that has embedded tabs and new lines.

I've googled and found that the XML parsing spec says the attribute text is "normalized", replacing white space characters with a blank.

I guess a have to replace the tabs and line breaks with an appropriate escaped character before I parse the XML.

In all of my googling I have not found a straightforward method to get from the File to a Document where the attribute text is returned with Tabs and Line breaks preserved.

The XML file is generated from a third party application so it may not be addressed there.

I want to use the JDK parser.

My initial attempts at reading the File into a string and parsing the String fail with a parse error on the first byte

Any suggestions on a straight forward approach?

An example element is at pastbin
    [Element example](https://pastebin.com/pc9uGbSD)

```
[1]: https://pastebin.com/pc9uGbSD
```

I perform a XML Parse like this

```
public ReadPlexExport(Path xmlPath, ExportType exType) throws Exception {
    this.xmlPath = xmlPath;
    this.type = exType;
    this.doc = DBF.newDocumentBuilder().parse(this.xmlPath.toFile());
}
```

Comment: You've not properly cited "the spec".  You've not shown your XML.  You've not shown any code.   If you'd like people to take time to help you, you should do your part and take time to provide a [mcve] that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution to my immediate problem was to read the XML file line by line as a text file, on each line replacing  \t characters with the escaped tab value, writing the line to a new file, then appending an escaped line break.

The new XML files could be parsed.  The original XML would always be in a form that allowed this hack as \t and line breaks would only ever occur in Attributes.